# Is using AlignWithMargins when spacing between controls good option?

Tags: delphi, alignment, panel, delphi-xe7

My old approach to space and align controls and panels on form was to use panels to distance another panel from form edges or another panels, controls. So, I would use a **lot** of panels for this.

Here is a simple example how I center Panel5 to be distanced, spaced 20px from every form edge:

[image]

This works good. And even if I make it very complex, have up 50 spaced, nested panels, it works good, no problems. But the maintenance is a hassle.

So, I 'discovered' AlignWithMargins and now I can center Panel5 like this:

[image]

And it works the same, but is much cleaner and a lot less panels.

But, I'm surprised that this property has been there for many many years and  I never noticed it. So, before I start changing all the tabs, all the forms, the question is:

**Is there anything I'm missing and putting too much pressure on this property to replace 100s of panels - Any obvious case where this doesn't work properly?**

I have total 550 panels on main form, probably 80% for this purpose. End user is not affected as they are distributed on 30 Tabs... so, result is clean and working.

**EDIT:**

Here is most common example how I use Panel to group controls together and can easily move them around, copy&paste and center or align in design or programmatically.
Each panel is in grey color.

[image]

Comment: The spacing panels are pointless. The align with margins is pointless. You likely don't even need the panels. What's wrong with Left and Top being set to 20.

Comment: Well, I use panels to group controls, I can move them around quickly, put border around if I need to, align, copy & paste... see example of most cases how i group controls and am able to arrange them.

Comment: They make sense for grouping for sure

Comment: If you are willing to pay/include 3rd party comtrols, Developer Express offers a very nice [Layout Control](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PiKmYwB__YE) that keeps the gui aligned.

Comment: I would use `AlignWithMargins` and I see no negative reason in doing so and as a bonus to not using several panels on the form - significantly smaller dfm size!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything I'm missing and putting too much pressure on this
>   property to replace 100s of panels - Any obvious case where this
>   doesn't work properly?

Yes, you can safely use `AlignWithMargins`.

I am using it all the time, and so far haven't had any issues with it. It is far better solution than your spacing panels.

Comment: Thank you. Found a comment online that TSplitter doesn't work when using panels with `AlignWithMargins`. It works OK in my XE7 version. Had any issues like that?

Comment: No, I haven't. But I don't use TSplitter much, since it is rather buggy control.

Comment: Thank you! I was waiting a bit to see if any issues come up by other users. Nothing did, so I will gladly start using this property.